# Symfony 4 Doctrine 2 findby dosent apply Join and custom join doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, query-builder

i'm relatively new with Symfony 4 and Doctrine ORM.
I'm trying to get all comments posted from one user when browsing this user profile page.

Here's my comment entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentsRepository")
 */
class Comments
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $auteur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $postedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default" : 0})
     */
    private $flagged;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" : 0})
     */
    private $validated;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cards", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="card_id")
     */
    private $postedOnCard;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users", inversedBy="commentsOnUser")
     */
    private $postedOnUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" : 0})
     */
    private $deleted;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuteur(): ?users
    {
        return $this->auteur;
    }

    public function setAuteur(?users $auteur): self
    {
        $this->auteur = $auteur;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->postedAt;
    }

    public function setPostedAt(\DateTimeInterface $postedAt): self
    {
        $this->postedAt = $postedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFlagged(): ?int
    {
        return $this->flagged;
    }

    public function setFlagged(int $flagged): self
    {
        $this->flagged = $flagged;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidated(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->validated;
    }

    public function setValidated(bool $validated): self
    {
        $this->validated = $validated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostedOnCard(): ?cards
    {
        return $this->postedOnCard;
    }

    public function setPostedOnCard(?cards $postedOnCard): self
    {
        $this->postedOnCard = $postedOnCard;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostedOnUser(): ?users
    {
        return $this->postedOnUser;
    }

    public function setPostedOnUser(?users $postedOnUser): self
    {
        $this->postedOnUser = $postedOnUser;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeleted(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    public function setDeleted(bool $deleted): self
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

when i'm trying to get all the comments from one user, i'm using this function

```
$coms_by_user = $com_repo->findBy(['auteur' => $user->getId()]);
```

$user is the route parameter, from /users/profile/$user and it works and returns me an array like this for an user with 2 comments posted:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Comments {#842 ▼
    -id: 11
    -auteur: Users {#497 ▼
      -id: 21
      -username: "testtttt"
      -password: "$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$S01Da1dseVBDQTBBZ0xJcQ$vvKB4Kfa7GLkhyMhbUqyC7PBjLA1doGxWPBPaXkd5bw"
      -email: "test.symfony@symfony.com"
      -firstName: "test"
      -lastName: "lol"
      -roles: array:1 [▶]
      -collection: PersistentCollection {#567 ▶}
      -wishlists: PersistentCollection {#493 ▶}
      -registeredAt: DateTime @1580322507 {#495 ▶}
      -comments: PersistentCollection {#427 ▶}
      -commentsOnUser: PersistentCollection {#429 ▶}
      -image: null
    }
    -postedAt: DateTime @1578960000 {#840 ▶}
    -content: "Hello !"
    -flagged: 0
    -validated: false
    -postedOnCard: Cards {#873 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -cardId: 117
      -cardName: null
      -cardSetNum: null
      -cardAlter: null
      -cardImage: null
      -cardColor: null
      -cardRarity: null
      -cardSet: null
      -cardType: null
      -comments: null
       …2
    }
    -postedOnUser: null
    -deleted: false
  }
  1 => Comments {#871 ▶}
]
```

As you can see, doctrine made an auto-join with users, giving me the username and all the datas of the comment author.
However, it didnt gave me the join between postedOnCard and the card where the comment was posted. So I cant have the card name, and everything else. (same problem for the one between postedOnUser and users)

SO I tried to make my own query, but I tried litteraly evrything and nothing seems to work. I always get an empty array.
The method I made to get all comments by username (from the route parameter) with the 3 joins (users, postedOnCard, postedOnUser)

```
/**
     * @return Comments[]
     * @param string $author
     */
    public function findAllWithLocation (string $author) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('com')
            ->addSelect('auteur', 'onCard', 'onUser')
            ->join('com.auteur'      , 'auteur')
            ->join('com.postedOnCard', 'onCard')
            ->join('com.postedOnUser', 'onUser')

            ->andWhere('auteur.username = :author')
            ->setParameter('author', $author)

            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
```

the method runs, but returns nothing. I really dont understand.
Also if someone could explain to me why all the find()/findBy/findOneBy ect default doctrine methods actually made joining with users automaticaly. Has the users table some kind of privileges ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default join is an inner join. That means, the record must exist.

I assume, your comment table has only ever either onUser or onCard but rarely or never both. Calling both `->join('com.onUser', 'onUser')` and `->join('com.onCard', 'onCard')` will lead to no records being returned.

This can be fixed by using `leftJoin` instead of `join` (rest remains the same).

Doctrine usually returns proxy objects, when the relation is not loaded. However, since your table (entity) contains the user id of the user to be loaded and that user already exists in doctrine's cache, the user will be placed there instead of the proxy object. This obviously isn't true for the other relations you have on your comment.

The user table doesn't have special privileges.

If you *always* want to load certain relations of an entity, have a look at eager loading (adding `fetch="EAGER"` to the `@ManyToOne` annotation).

Comment: Thank you ! It works.
I though the join was a shorthand for leftjoin, not innerjoin. I even tried ->innerjoin.
thank you for the explanations, it make perfect sense to me now.